# How to Determine if Error Occured in this Case (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nserror

Hey guys, I have this function:

```
//retrieves checksum within core data store, returns 0 if a checksum has not been stored
-(double)getStoredChecksum {
    NSError *error;
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription 
                                   entityForName:@"DataFeedManager" inManagedObjectContext:[self managedObjectContext]];
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];
    NSArray *fetchedObjects = [[self managedObjectContext] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
    //+for (NSManagedObject* item in fetchedObjects) //REMOVE
        //+[[self managedObjectContext] deleteObject:item]; //REMOVE FOR CLEARING CHECKSUM CONTENTS

    if ([fetchedObjects count] == 0){ //array is empty
        NSLog(@"FETCHED OBJECTS IS EMPTY");
        checksumStored = NO;
        return 0;
    }
    if (fetchedObjects == nil) {
        NSLog(@"Error while fetching\n%@",
              ([error localizedDescription] != nil) ? [error localizedDescription] : @"Unknown Error");
    }
    if ([fetchedObjects count] > 1)
        NSLog(@"====BAD:Multiple Checksums Retrieved!!!!====");
    checksumStored = YES;
    double returnable = [[[fetchedObjects objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"lastUpdateCheckSum"] doubleValue];
    return returnable;
}//getStoredChecksum()
```

As you can see, it executes a fetch request, however I am unsure of how to check if an error occurred. As you can see, I am checking to see if the array is empty via `[fetchedObjects count] == 0` however, I heard somewhere that if the error occurs and the array is nil, 0 is returned for count as well, thus it is safe to test for array emptiness that way, but it masks my check for a null array. Thus the problem is that I have no definitive way of checking if an error occurred. Any thoughts on how I should go about doing this?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

How would I check for an error in this case?

```
NSUInteger numEntities = [[self managedObjectContext] countForFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];
```

As NSUInteger is specified as an unsigned int, so I can't even assign it a value of -1 and check for a -1 later if I wanted to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>Set `error` to `nil` before calling `executeFetchRequest::`. If `error` is not `nil` after then it was set and thus an error occured.</strike>

The reason the `count` check is masking the `nil` check is because any message sent to `nil` returns `nil` which in this case is also 0. This can be easily fixed by checking for `nil` first, or modify your `if` statement so it is as followed:

```
if (fetchedObjects && [fetchedObjects count] == 0){
```

For the case with `countForFetchRequest::` `NSNotFound` is returned when an error occurs, so just check for that.

Comment: So if the array is nil, i.e. empty, error will be set to something?

Comment: `nil` is not the same as empty. An empty array means no objects were fetched. `nil` being returned means an error occured. See http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/CoreDataFramework/Classes/NSManagedObjectContext_Class/NSManagedObjectContext.html

Comment: Ok this works thanks! I would accept this as the answer if I didn't come across another case which I am stumped on (see EDITed portion above).

Comment: If it works, then accept the answer, and instead of appending another question to your original, make a new one! This isn't a forum!

Comment: I'd rather ask similar questions in one thread, keeps everything organized and easy to find, especially for others with the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Copy & pasted from the docs for `countForFetchRequest:error:`

> **Return Value**
>
> The number of objects a given fetch request would have returned if it had been passed to executeFetchRequest:error:, or NSNotFound if an error occurs.

So,

```
if (numEntities == NSNotFound) {
    // Handle the error
}
```

Comment: Wow, OK, that is not mentioned in my copy of the documentation: "Return Value
The number of objects a given fetch request would have returned if it had been passed to executeFetchRequest:error:." Thanks for the help!

Comment: Yep - you're right. The Xcode 3.2 docs don't mention NSNotFound. The ones with Xcode 4 & online both do.